# componentDidMount() of parent is not called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, inheritance, ecmascript-6

I have BaseComponent, from which all another components inherit. But if child component has `componentDidMount()`, parent's `componentDidMount()` is not called. Is there any way to call `componentDidMount()` of parent's component always after `componentDidMount()` of child component? Here is [example](http://jsfiddle.net/o5L8g4ra/97/).

Comment: Why you want to call componentDidMount of parent? Can you explaine the use case?

Comment: [Facebook discourages using inheritance with react components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "super()" function to call the parents implementation.

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log('Child mounted.');
    super();
}
```

**But** this is regarded as an anti-pattern. The suggested approach would be composition (details [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#specialization)). Unfortunately, without know what you are trying to accomplish through inheritance, we can't tell you an alternative through composition. In using your example, it can be done something like this

```
class Animal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('Parent mounted.'); // Not working.
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>{this.props.animalType}</div>);
    }
}

class Dog extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('Child mounted.');
    }

    render() {
        return (<Animal animalType="Dog" />);
    }
}

React.render(<Dog />, document.body);
```

Comment: Thanks, but in `componentDidMount()` of child I call `super.componentDidMount()` instead `super()`, because `super()` can be called only from `constructor`.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, your parent component `Animal` is not actually the parent but is an independent component since anyways you are rendering the `Dog` component.

This is the Reason that the `componentDidMount` of `Animal` Component is not getting called, in fact the `Animal component` itself is not being rendered but just defined.

In order for `Dog` to be a child of `Animal` component, render it from the Parent component(`Animal`) and change the code like

```
class Animal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('Parent mounted.'); // Not working.
    }
    render() {
    return (
         <Dog/>
    )

    }

}

class Dog extends Animal {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('Child mounted.');
    }

    render() {
        return <div>Dog.</div>;
    }
}
React.render(<Animal />, document.body);
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/o5L8g4ra/98/)**

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?

Comment: This is a wrong implementation. The parent class should never know anything of its subclasses and here the `Animal` class is rendering a subclass (`Dog`).
What if we create a new class `Cat` that extends Animal? What should now `Animal` render?